# Syntactical definition of 'commander' in 'Commander, Fleet Activities [USN base]'

Tags: military

What is the syntactical definition of the word 'commander' in e.g. 'Commander, Fleet Activities Yokosuka'?

I always figured it was the Commander **of** Fleet Activities Yokosuka, i.e. the commanding officer in charge of the US Navy base, but the commanding officer of Yokosuka is introduced as "Commander, Fleet Activities Yokosuka's Commanding Officer, Captain [name]".

Comment: Where did you see the second example?

Comment: "Commander, Fleet Activities Yokosuka's Commanding Officer, Captain [name]" ? On the Armed Forces Network's local radio station here, in one of their infomercials with an announcement from the CO.

Comment: I don't understand why "Commander" and "Commanding Officer" are both used. "Commander, Fleet Activities Yokosuka, (rank, name)" is fairly standard military and naval speech and "Fleet Activities Yokosuka's Commanding Officer (rank, name)" is one of several ways it can be said in civilian speech. I suspect that the announcer got themselves into a bit of a knot, started using the naval phraseology then continued with one of the civilian forms.

Comment: Exactly, which is why it confused me that "Commander Fleet Activities Yokosuka" (or its abbreviation, "CFAY") is used to refer to the USN base, not the office of the commanding officer of that base:

https://www.naval-technology.com/projects/commanderfa/

Comment: The last comment here explains the text in the question. The first comma is part of the base's name. Therefore, the construction of the sentence is simply "CFAY's Commanding Officer, Captain [name]." *Commanding Officer* is the ***role***, *Captain* is the ***rank***.

Comment: As for the terminology of *CFAT* itself, it's because the base, in an anthropomorphized sense, is the "commander" of the fleet operations. It's unusual. In more standard English, it would normally be expressed as **Command Base, Fleet Activities Yokusuka**. I have no idea what the origin is of using *Commander* over *Command Base* in this case.